# Alternative to coefficient of variation (CV)/relative standard error as a measure of estimate's reliability/stability

Tags: coefficient-of-variation

I am seeking a statistic measuring an estimate's reliability or stability as an alternative to the coefficient of variation (CV), also known as the relative standard error. The CV is the standard error of an estimate (proportion, mean, regression coefficient, etc.) divided by the estimate itself, usually expressed as a percentage. For example, if a survey finds 15% unemployment with a 6% standard error, the CV is .06/.15 = .4 = 40%.

Some US government agencies flag or suppress as unreliable any estimate with a CV over a certain threshold such as 30% or 50%. But this standard can be arbitrary (for example, 85% employment would have a much lower CV of .06/.85 = 7%) and has other limitations (such as when the estimate is zero).

Can anyone suggest an alternative measure of stability or reliability?

Comment: You are welcome to include contact information in your site profile, David, but inserting that in a question, answer, or comment is contrary to site policy.